# Flex items are not equal width

Tags: css, flexbox

I'd like to create a grid system using only `flexbox`.

It seems to not be working when the children have no content.

As you can see below, the last child in the last row doesn't align.

```css
.flexline {
  display: flex;
}

.flexline.is-full>* {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flexline.is-full>.is-taking-2 {
  flex-grow: 2;
}


/* color */

.flexline {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.12);
  height: 60px;
}

.flexline>* {
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.33);
  margin: 5px;
}


/* /color */
```

```html
<div class="flexline is-full">
  <div>x</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>x</div>
</div>
<div class="flexline is-full">
  <div>x</div>
  <div class="is-taking-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that the first line has 6 horizontal margins, and the second line has four. `6 * 5px = 30px` and `4 * 5px = 20px`. So there is a 10px differential. See the duplicate for a more complete explanation and solutions.

Comment: Ok, so, if I remove the entire margins, the shift will be disappeared ?